# C++ Undefined Reference to Function of Dynamically Created Class Member

Tags: c++, linker-errors, new-operator

I have four different C++ classes; `Comp()`, which contains `Parent()`, which has two children `ChildA()` and `ChildB()`. I want to dynamically create an instance of `ChildA` or `ChildB` inside of `Comp()` depending on some parameter.

My code looks a bit like this:

```
class Parent {
  public:
    foo();
};

class ChildA : public Parent {
  public:
    foo(); // Overrides Parent.foo()
};

class ChildB : public Parent {
  public:
    foo(); // Overrides Parent.foo()
};

class Comp {
  public:
    Init(uint8_t someParam){
      if(someParam){
        obj = new ChildA();
      }
      else{
        obj = new ChildB();
      }
    }

    doFoo(){
        obj->foo();
    }
 
  private:
    Parent* obj;
};
```

However, this does not compile. It's throwing me linker errors saying that I have an undefined reference to `Parent::foo()`

```
/build/libComp.a(Comp.cpp.o): In function `Comp::doFoo()':
Comp.cpp:(.text._ZN6Memory8readByteEt+0x4e): undefined reference to `Parent::foo()'
```

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. I'm coming from a background in Python programming so I haven't quite switched my thought process over to C++ yet. Am I allowed to use classes this way?

Comment: Why not C&P all your code? Not just pseudo code. there is important information missing that would help us solve your issue.

Comment: Since `foo` isn't virtual then calling it from a `Parent` pointer will call `Parent::foo()` which I don't see an implementation for in your example. If you want to call the function in the child class you need to make it virtual. You'll still need to provide an implementation for the parent function unless you make it pure virtual and require each child to implement it.

Comment: This sounds about right. Let me give it a shot

Comment: @Andy please do not ask for "all code". Always ask for a MRE, a [mre]. Type `[mre]` in a comment like yours.

Comment: Using `Parent` before its declaration might be problematic. What happens if you move the Parent class before the others?

Comment: That's how it is my actual code (everything is defined in seperate files). Let me update the question.

Comment: Making `foo()` a `virtual` method introduced new errors, `undefined reference to \`vtable for Parent\``. Trying to work through this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are a Python programmer you got used to the world where every method is a virtual one, and the overload means that you just replace the value in the dict. C++ is somewhat different.

So the first solution is to define the `Parent::foo` method. You have declared it, the class is not a template - so you have to define the body somewhere. Anyway that wouldn't help you as calling `obj->foo();` means calling the `Parent::foo()` method, and I guess that is not what you want.

Now we are moving to the world of virtual methods: in C++ you have to declare a method as `virtual` explicitly:

```
class Parent {
  public:
    virtual foo();
};
```

You still need to define the body of `Parent::foo()` somewhere.

If you don't want to define it by design, you may make this method *abstract* (thus the class `Parent` becomes abstract as well, and no instance of this class can be created):

```
class Parent {
  public:
    virtual foo() = 0;
};
```

You don't need to declare the method `foo` of the derived classes as virtual (they will be anyway), but the best practice is to add either a `override` or `final` specifier:

```
class ChildA : public Parent {
  public:
    foo() final; // Overrides Parent.foo()
};

class ChildB : public Parent {
  public:
    foo() override; // Overrides Parent.foo()
};
```

The difference is that you cannot override this method for `ClassA` and you can do this for the `ClassB`.